# Accessing data inside an array via pointer error

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I have 2 files in msg format. msg format is not important here.

car.msg

```
int speed;
int width;
```

cararr.msg

```
car mycar[];
```

I want to print all the information about all the cars that are present but I have no clue about the number of cars present(how big is the array) so I use the following technique to print the information.

so I do this:

```
cararr* ptr2car;
for(int i=0;mycar[i] != '\0'; i++){
      cout << ptr2car->mycar[i].speed <<endl;
      cout << ptr2car->mycar[i].width <<endl;
}
```

Despite this, I am receiving errors. I do not know what did I do wrong. I have no clue what approach should I use to get this output. please Help

Also why should I take a pointer to cararr, when I can just take an instance of cararr inst2car and do something like this:

```
 cararr inst2car;
    for(int i=0;mycar[i] != '\0'; i++){
          cout << inst2car.mycar[i].speed <<endl;
          cout << inst2car.mycar[i].width <<endl;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: does `cararr` have a `mycar` member? also you may wanna try only `mycar[i]` instead of `mycar[i] != '\0'`

Comment: This all really really depends on what the msg file is (are you using ROS?), what the structure generated for those files are, how the data obtained etc. For example, you don't show us how `ptr2car` is instantiated. Maybe it's dynamic memory so it has to be pointer.

Comment: By the way, you use `ptr2car->mycar` inside the loop, but only `mycar` as the loop condition. Is that your compilation error? Not to mention you can't compare a struct with an integer.

Comment: Yes I am using ROS. I think the problem is that I cannot use mycar[i] != '\0' because its not a char. Also maybe I should also change the loop condition and add ptr2car->mycar[i] in the loop. I will check and inform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need to know exactly what's at the end of the array. You need some sort of sentinel value to use as a delimiter to indicate the end of the array.

'\0' used in c strings is an example of such delimiter.

You need to ensure the last element in the array is such delimiter and check for it in the condition.

It's hard to give you more specific answer with such generic question.

For example, if you knew the last element will have speed -1, you can use that:

```
for(int i=0;mycar[i].speed != -1; i++) {
```

Comment: Yeah thats the problem. I am detecting different cars and I have no clue about the number or the parameters of the car. Everytime there might be a different reading.